# Find the value of $(-1)^{1/3}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Evaluate $(-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

I've tried to answer it by letting it be $x$ so that $x^3+1=0$.
But by this way, I'll get $3$ roots, how do I get the actual answer of $(-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$??

Comment: What is your definition of $(\cdot)^{\frac{1}{3}}$?

Comment: This is a related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109484/find-all-reals-a-b-for-which-ab-is-also-real

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends whether you are trying to solve it as an equation over the reals ($\mathbb{R}$) or over the complex plane ($\mathbb{C}$).
The polynomial $x^3+1$ factors as $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$. So in the first case, you have exactly one solution: $x=-1$, since the second polynomial has no real roots. If you're looking for roots over $\mathbb{C}$, then you'll have three roots, since the $\sqrt[3]t$ is not a function over $\mathbb{C}$, hence all the 3 roots have equal rights to be called "the root".

Comment: It is also ture for 1^(1/3), I think.

Comment: @eccstartup: Sure, it's true for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried looking for factors of $(x+y)^3$  ??

$(x+y)^3 = (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$
therefore
$(x+1)^3 = (x+1)(x^2-x+1) \Rightarrow x=-1$ is one of the root, and apply methods you learnt to find roots of quadratic equation to find other roots.

Answer (score 1):

They are all equally considered to be values of $\sqrt[3]{-1}$. There is no unique cube root, just as there is no unique square root.

Answer (score -1):

Just put it like complex numbers:

We know that $z=\sqrt[k]{m_\theta}$, so

$z=\sqrt[3]{-1}$

$-1=1_{\pi}$

$\alpha_n=\dfrac{\theta+k\pi}{n}$

$\alpha_0=60$

$\alpha_1=180$

$\alpha_2=300$

So the answers are:

$z_1=1_{\pi/3}$

$z_2=1_{\pi}$

$z_3=1_{5\pi/3}$

Comment: This uses [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers).