# Fractional exponents and when they commute.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

In any elementary algebra class students are taught that if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, $x^{a/b}=(\sqrt[b]{x})^{a}$ or $\sqrt[b]{x^{a}}$. But only after teaching this lesson I realized this isn't always true. Permit us to work over $\mathbb{C}$. Then compute $(-1)^{3/2}$. If we do

$$(\sqrt[2]{-1})^{3}=i^{3}\neq -i=\sqrt{(-1)^{3}}$$

So my question is under what conditions is $x^{a/b}=(\sqrt[b]{x})^{a}$ for $x\in\mathbb{C}$, $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$?

In the case where it doesn't commute like above, how are we to define $x^{a/b}$? It can't be two numbers.

Is this something often studied? Or is it known and most of the time it's not interesting?

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws  and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentLaws.html

Comment: This link has nothing to do with my question since it doesn't address fractional exponents.

Comment: @TheNumebr23, in the first link, $x,y$ are real right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee true $x$ and $y$ are real but using the information there it says $a^{x}=a^{x}$. It in no ways discusses the problem I posed above. I'm interested in things like $(-1)^{3/2}$ and what it's value is. Not how to use exponent rules.

Comment: Everything is fine when the base is real.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't well-defined, because there is not a generally agreed-upon meaning for $\sqrt[b]{x}$ in the case where $x$ is a complex number.  One possibility is to use the *principal root*, i.e. the root in the upper half-plane with the smallest argument, but this definition is not consistent with the usual convention that $\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109484/find-all-reals-a-b-for-which-ab-is-also-real/109498#109498) for further discussion of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a similarly noteworthy situation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy#Positive_and_negative_roots) involving the roots of negative numbers.  In brief, the problem comes down to the fact that there's no universal choice of "principle $n$th root" of a complex number that will allow $(ab)^\frac1n=(a)^\frac1n (b)^\frac 1n$ for all choices of $a,b$.

This does not fully answer your question. However, I hope you find it to be a helpful first step.